# Record audio while holding a button, replay it on release and overwrite the previous file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to record audio while I'm pressing a button and replay it when I release the button.

It works fine for the first time, but when I record one more time, it appends the new record to the existing one. I can't figure out how to replace the file instead of appending to it.
I've tried to delete it when I start to record, but it can't create a new one.
Basically, I'd like to overwrite the file, instead of appending the sound to it.

```py
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
import sched
from pygame import mixer

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []


def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    frames.append(in_data)
    return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue


class MyListener(keyboard.Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(self.on_press, self.on_release)
        self.key_pressed = None
        self.wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
        self.wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
        self.wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
        self.wf.setframerate(RATE)

    def on_press(self, key):
        if key.char == 'r':
            self.key_pressed = True
        return True

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key.char == 'r':
            self.key_pressed = False
        return True


listener = MyListener()
listener.start()
started = False
stream = None


def recorder():
    global started, p, stream, frames

    if listener.key_pressed and not started:
        # Start the recording
        try:
            stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                            channels=CHANNELS,
                            rate=RATE,
                            input=True,
                            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                            stream_callback=callback)
            print("Stream active:", stream.is_active())
            started = True
            print("start Stream")
        except:
            raise

    elif not listener.key_pressed and started:
        try:
            started = False
            print("Stop recording")
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()
            listener.wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))

            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load("output.wav")
            mixer.music.set_volume(0.8)
            mixer.music.play()
        except:
            raise

    # Reschedule the recorder function in 100 ms.
    task.enter(0.1, 1, recorder, ())


print("Press and hold the 'r' key to begin recording")
print("Release the 'r' key to end recording")
task = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
task.enter(0.1, 1, recorder, ())
task.run()
```

Comment: I've tried something like that, but not sure if I did it correctly. Could you show me your idea on my code please?

Comment: Added ```open, setnchannels, setsampwifth, setframerate``` right before the ```writeframes``` part, then added ```wf.close(), steam.stop_stream(), stream.close()``` and it still apends to the file.

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: You are right, added ```frames = [ ]``` right after ```mixer.music.play()``` solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues I found:

- You don't close the wave file after writing to it
- You don't reset the `frames` buffer between writes
- Pygame seems to be locking the file so a 2nd write attempt fails. I could not figure out how to get Pygame to unlock the file, so I switched to Playsound.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
import sched
from playsound import playsound

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
frames = []

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    frames.append(in_data)
    return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue

class MyListener(keyboard.Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(self.on_press, self.on_release)
        self.key_pressed = None

    def on_press(self, key):
        if key.char == 'r':
            self.key_pressed = True
        return True

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key.char == 'r':
            self.key_pressed = False
        return True

listener = MyListener()
listener.start()
started = False
stream = None

def recorder():
    global started, p, stream, frames

    if listener.key_pressed and not started:
        # Start the recording
        try:
            # Reset buffer
            frames = []
            stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                            channels=CHANNELS,
                            rate=RATE,
                            input=True,
                            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                            stream_callback=callback)
            print("Stream active:", stream.is_active())
            started = True
            print("start Stream")
        except:
            raise

    elif not listener.key_pressed and started:
        try:
            started = False
            print("Stop recording")
            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()

            # Using with will close the file automatically
            with wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb') as wf:
                wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
                wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
                wf.setframerate(RATE)
                wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))

            # No issues with playsound locking the file
            playsound(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME)
        except:
            raise

    # Reschedule the recorder function in 100 ms.
    task.enter(0.1, 1, recorder, ())


print("Press and hold the 'r' key to begin recording")
print("Release the 'r' key to end recording")
task = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
task.enter(0.1, 1, recorder, ())
task.run()
```

And just for fun, I changed your program to use callbacks only instead of constantly polling:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import pyaudio
import wave
from playsound import playsound

CHUNK = 8192
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

class recorder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.recording = False
        
    def start(self):
        if self.recording: return
        try:
            self.frames = []
            self.stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                            channels=CHANNELS,
                            rate=RATE,
                            input=True,
                            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                            stream_callback=self.callback)
            print("Stream active:", self.stream.is_active())
            print("start Stream")
            self.recording = True
        except:
            raise

    def stop(self):
        if not self.recording: return
        self.recording = False
        print("Stop recording")
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()

        with wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb') as wf:
            wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
            wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
            wf.setframerate(RATE)
            wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
        playsound(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME)

    def callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        self.frames.append(in_data)
        return in_data, pyaudio.paContinue

class MyListener(keyboard.Listener):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(self.on_press, self.on_release)
        self.recorder = recorder();

    def on_press(self, key):
        if key.char == 'r':
            self.recorder.start()
        return True

    def on_release(self, key):
        if key.char == 'r':
            self.recorder.stop();
            return True
        # Any other key ends the program
        return False

print("Press and hold the 'r' key to begin recording")
print("Release the 'r' key to end recording")

# Collect events until released
with MyListener() as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

[audiomath](https://pypi.org/project/audiomath) provides some high-level classes that can help with tasks like this. Like `pyaudio`, it also wraps around PortAudio to allow recording and playback. Below is a shorter audiomath-based listing.

I'm guessing you probably don't sit with your finger on the 'r' button for longer than a few seconds. In that case, it's more efficient to pre-allocate several seconds of space in memory (provided it's more than enough) and record into/play back from that. For the sound you want to keep, you can always say `player.sound.Write('output.wav')` at the end. Or you can uncomment the line that saves every attempt.

If for any reason you definitely do want to stream open-endedly to a file while recording, you can supply a filename in the constructor and that will get passed to the `Recorder` instance (the memory-resident `self.buffer` still exists: it's a circular buffer retaining the last N seconds). Streaming to file requires an external `ffmpeg` installation, though. Note that audiomath's playback loads the entire thing back into memory, so nothing has really been made more memory-efficient overall...

Because of the use of `ffmpeg`, you can also stream directly to other audio formats, other than `.wav` if you want.

```
import time
import pynput
import audiomath as am  

class MyListener(pynput.keyboard.Listener):
    def __init__(self, filename=None, buffer_length_seconds=10):
        """
        Note:
        
        If you specify a long enough `buffer_length_seconds` for your
        purposes, then you do not need to record to file and so do not
        need to specify `filename`.
        
        If you specify `filename`, you need to have installed `ffmpeg`
        (see the help for `audiomath.ffmeg.Install`).
        """
        super(MyListener, self).__init__(self.on_press, self.on_release)
        self.key_pressed = None
        
        self.queue = []
        self.filename = filename
        self.buffer_length_seconds = buffer_length_seconds
        self.new_recorder()
        
    def new_recorder( self ):
        self.buffer = am.Sound(self.buffer_length_seconds, nChannels=2, fs=44100)
        self.recorder = am.Recorder(self.buffer, loop=True, recording=False, filename=self.filename)
        
    def on_press(self, key):
        try: key.char
        except: return
        if key.char == 'r' and not self.key_pressed:
            print('recording...')
            self.recorder.Record()
            self.key_pressed = True
        return True

    def on_release(self, key):
        try: key.char
        except: return
        if key.char == 'r' and self.key_pressed:
            print('finished')
            self.recorder.Stop()
            self.recorder = None # seems to be necessary when filename is used, to ensure the ffmpeg process and file are closed and cleaned up
            if self.filename:
                player = am.Player( self.filename )
            else:
                player = am.Player( self.buffer )
                # self.buffer.Write( 'output.wav')  # if you want to ensure every attempt gets saved. File will be overwritten.
            self.queue.append( player )
            self.new_recorder()
            self.key_pressed = False
        return True

#with MyListener('output.wav') as listener:  # this variant uses a file (and needs ffmpeg)
with MyListener() as listener:               # this variant just records to memory
    while True:
        if listener.queue:
            player = listener.queue.pop( 0 )
            player.Play()
        time.sleep(0.1)
```